# Plot regression lines in r with multiple dummy variables

Tags: r, lm

I have a regression analysis with several dummy variables, and I want to plot the regression line in a figure. The dummy variables is Chinese actors, Chinese co production company and filming location in china. How can I plot this in a figure?

```r
control.test <-lm(CBO.split~ Chinese.actors + Chinese.co...production.company..yes.1.no.0. + Filming.location.China..yes.1.no.0.)
summary(control.test)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get a better response if you provide some sample data with accompanying code. It is also not entirely clear what exactly you want to plot; the observed versus fitted values?

Comment: Hi, thanks. so CBO.split stands for Chinese box office revenue. I was trying to use the function ggplot, to plot cbo.split in the xlab while all other in the ylab.

Comment: See the `predict()` function. This will accept the model and data frame of values and predict the output values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
levels(iris$Species)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Now a regression model that uses `Species` as a dummy variable.

```
iris.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Species, iris)
iris.coef <- coef(iris.lm)
iris.coef
#       (Intercept)       Sepal.Width Speciesversicolor  Speciesvirginica 
#         2.2513932         0.8035609         1.4587431         1.9468166
```

The `Intercept` is the value of `Sepal.Length` when `Sepal.Width` equals 0 for species `setosa`, `Intercept` + `Speciesversicolor` is the intercept for `versicolor` and `Intercept` + `Speciesvirginica` is the intercept for `virginica`. The slopes for all three lines are the same. Finally we plot the results:

```
plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, iris, pch=16, col=as.numeric(Species)+1)
abline(a=iris.coef[1], b=iris.coef[2], col=2)
abline(a=iris.coef[1] + iris.coef[3], b=iris.coef[2], col=3)
abline(a=iris.coef[1] + iris.coef[4], b=iris.coef[2], col=4)
legend("bottomright", levels(iris$Species), pch=16, lwd=1, col=2:4)
```

[image: Regression Lines]

Your case is slightly more complicated because you have two dichotomous variables, but they affect only the intercept, the slope will not change.